# Tower of hanoi using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI for a tower of Hanoi application using Qt. I Already wrote the C++ code using recursion but I am a total beginner when it comes to working with Qt and creating GUI's and have just started familiarizing myself with it by creating a simple calculator GUI but don't have a clear idea how to tackle the Tower of Hanoi GUI especially on how to create the disks and pegs graphically.
Any tips or pointers on where to start would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities, but for the beginning, I'd recommend to just place a few buttons and move them around accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at `QGraphicsScene`. It will take a while to get familiar, but it is the proper Qt tool for handling these kind of things.

Basically, `QGraphicsScene` is an abstract representation of, well, a graphics scene. It is a virtual canvas object to which you can add graphics items (`QAbstractGraphicsItems`) with various shapes and positions. It can then be rendered in a specialized view class called `QGraphicsView`.

A good starting point is the '40000 chips' example in Qt Creator.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend 2 options:

One would be using an OpenGL canvas inside your window and have objects loaded into your 2D scene. And when you need to move or rotate the objects, you would just need to know about translate and  rotate functionalities.

You wouldn't need to do this with modern OpenGL, as it might be overwhelming at the starts. But OpenGL with fixed pipeline (legacy version) would be quite easy to learn. However, I should  mention that QT and OpenGL can be a little trouble to use together   for a beginner due to QT.

The other would be the QPainter to load and draw 2D images (of components of towers). It wouldn't be as realistic as an OpenGL equavelent, but it would get the job done as well.

You can find the functions available via QPainter in the following link. It has almost everything you would need and to move a part, just render using the initial position values added to the offset.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html

I also recommend watching a few videos on Youtube about translation in computer graphics, to understand the logic behind this common functionality about moving things in a scene in amounts dependent on other conditions.